# Woocommerce custom checkout form

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, forms

I would like to customize my checkout form. I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom form by creating my own inputs while using the same field names and action as the original form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite [woocommerce templates](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/release/3.2/templates) placing them in your theme. To overwrite e.g. `form-billing.php` template, place it in `yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php` directory.

You can also add [filter](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f2d2077c30f156a055ee19c07a8e6c4e81fd6228/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2110) to overwrite form field rendering function. Or even [overwrite](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f2d2077c30f156a055ee19c07a8e6c4e81fd6228/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1902) whole function.

To add new fields refer to [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-7).

I'm pasting code from documentation for adding fields to not leave answer only with link:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field' );

function wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_process');

function wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['field_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['field_name'] ) );
    }
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function wpse_287663_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true ) . '</p>';
}
```